# Read and Display two CSV files in PHP

Tags: php

I'm new to PHP, and the best way for me to learn something is a test project, so...  What I'm trying to do is make a program that lets users define core of a code string, and then upload a csv of variables that gets put into it.  The example I'm using is making a set of HTML list items, so the end code would be:

```
<li><span class="label">VARAIBLE1:</span> <span class="value">VARIABLE2</span></li>
```

So, for VARIABLE1 they could upload a csv of items like 
          Batman,Calvin,Simon,Rocky 
and for VARIABLE2 a separate csv with 
          Robin,Hobbes,Garfunkel,Bullwinkle

This would in turn generate

```
<li><span class="label">Batman:</span> <span class="value">Robin</span></li>
<li><span class="label">Calvin:</span> <span class="value">Hobbes</span></li>
<li><span class="label">Simon:</span> <span class="value">Garfunkel</span></li>
<li><span class="label">Rocky:</span> <span class="value">Bullwinkle</span></li>
```

So far, here is the PHP I've scraped together.

```
$t1 = htmlspecialchars('<li><span class="label">');
    $csv1 = fopen('http://viai.co/viai/viaidev/stringvariable/String%20Creator/csv1.csv', 'r');
    fclose($csv1);
    $t2 = htmlspecialchars('</span><span class="value">');
    $csv2 = fopen('http://viai.co/viai/viaidev/stringvariable/String%20Creator/csv2.csv', 'r');
        while (($line2 = fgetcsv($csv2)) !== FALSE) {
        //$line is an array of the csv elements
        print_r($line2);
        }
    fclose($csv2);
    $t3 = htmlspecialchars('</span></li>');


    $len = max(count($csv1), count($csv2));
        for($i=0; $i<$len; $i++){
        $csv1 = isset($csv1[$i]) ? $csv1[$i] : '';
        $csv2 = isset($csv2[$i]) ? $csv2[$i] : '';
        echo $t1.$csv1.$t2.$csv2.$t3;}
```

At some point I was able to get this to work with sets of arrays I typed in the PHP, but I'd like it to be read from uploaded CSVs.  Any guidance would be awesome, and thanks in advance!

Comment: Not an answer, but you should look at using file_get_contents() instead of fopen and fclose.

Comment: Why not a csv with `Batman,Robin` & `Calvin,Hobbes`, etc.? Seems more userfriendly, and easier in your code, a win-win ;)

Answer (score 0):

You have mentioned that your data is in CSV format but it is in the format of one item for each line so I considered `"\n"` rather than `","` to [explode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) it .

```
Label 1
Label 2
Label 3
...

Description 1
Description 2
Description 3
...
```

So you could do [file_get_contents](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) and then [explode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) the data .

```
$data1 = file_get_contents( "http://viai.co/viai/viaidev/stringvariable/String%20Creator/csv1.csv" ,false );

$dataArray1 = explode( "\n" ,$data1 ); // Use "," instead if your data is CSV

var_dump( $dataArray1 ); // For test

$data2 = file_get_contents( "http://viai.co/viai/viaidev/stringvariable/String%20Creator/csv2.csv" ,false );

$dataArray2 = explode( "\n" ,$data2 ); // Use "," instead if your data is CSV

var_dump( $dataArray2 ); // For test

// Rest of your code to iterate through the arrays and display the info
```